nginx proxy_ssl_certificate/proxy_ssl_certificate_key forward client certificate?
We've setup nginx ingress with mTLS enabled and we do observe that it's working fine,
However, we have a use case:
1, we have nginx-ingress(mtls enabled, ssl_verify_client=optional)  with proxy-pass working in region Acme1, we can see the client certificate when "direct" hit with SSL Client Certificate and SSL Key Certificate passed on
2, we have nginx-ingress(mtls enabled, ssl_verify_client=optional)  with proxy-pass working in region Acme2, we can see the client certificate when "direct" hit with SSL Client Certificate and SSL Key Certificate passed on

in Acme1 nginx-ingress, we add "failover" mechanism to Acme2 nginx-ingress, we confirm everything is working good and legit.

Before setting ssl_verify_client=on on both Acme1 and Acme2, in Acme1, added these below lines


            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
            proxy_ssl_certificate certs/ca.crt;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key certs/key.crt;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate certs/rootca.pem;

as well as under "/location", included below lines
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
            proxy_set_header X-Client-Cert $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

And in ACME2,  we observe that we are seeing certificate as per proxy_ssl_certificate/proxy_ssl_certificate_key/proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate (that is forwarded from  ACME1 nginx only)  when spillover/failover happens from Acme1 Nginx-ingress.  How do we be able to completely forward the client certificate when hit at ACME1 and spillover/failover to  ACME2?
ACME2 have this below already
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: root-ca
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream-header: "x-forwarded-client-cert"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "2"

Expecting what should be tweaked in order to completely forward client certificate when hit to ACME1 nginx and be able to include in ACME2 nginx.

Never mind - this instruction helps!
Need Certificate chain (on the incoming interface) from Nginx
TODO :
nginx1 -
proxy_set_header X-Client-Cert $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
nginx2 -

read/parse the incomng headers
extract/fetch X-Client-Cert
use it as per https://clairekeum.wordpress.com/2018/12/05/passing-client-cert-through-nginx-to-the-backend/

